# Import Data from Postgresql to Hive

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am facing issues while importing Table from postgresql to hive. Query I am using is :

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:postgresql://IP:5432/PROD_DB \
--username ABC_Read \
--password ABC@123 \
--table vw_abc_cust_aua \
-- --schema ABC_VIEW \
--target-dir /tmp/hive/raw/test_trade \
--fields-terminated-by "\001" \
--hive-import \
--hive-table vw_abc_cust_aua \
--m 1
```

Error I am getting

> ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: No primary key could be found for table vw_abc_cust_aua. Please specify one with --split-by or perform a sequential import with '-m 1'.

PLease let me know what is wrong with my query

Answer (score 0):

I am considering `-- --schema ABC_VIEW` is a typo error, it should be `--schema ABC_VIEW`

The other issue is the option to provide number of mapper is either `-m` or `--num-mappers` and not `--m`

**Solution**

in you script change `--m` to `-m` or `--num-mappers`

Comment: -- -- schema ABC_VIEW isnt a typo error. Its to get quotes around Schema while the query is executing.

Comment: Already tried -m and --num-mappers but still getting same error.

Comment: @RaghavMehta you need to provide `-m 1`